# Angular 14: How to move to the left datepicker panel from Prime-ng

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, calendar, primeng

I need to move to the left of the panel shown in the `<p-calendar>`. In my case, the date-picker must be moved to the left because there is a splitter on the right.

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-12">
              <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="col-6 mt-5" style="margin-left:-2%;">
                  <div class="form-input p-float-label">
                    <p-calendar inputId="fromDate" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [showTime]="true"
                      [maxDate]="form.get('toDate').value" [readonlyInput]="true" [monthNavigator]="true"
                      [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2020:{{ currentYear }}" [locale]="locale"
                      formControlName="fromDate">
                    </p-calendar>
                    <label for="fromDate">{{ 'devices.general.from' | translate }}</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-5 mb-4">
                  <div class="form-input p-float-label">
                    <p-calendar inputId="toDate" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [showTime]="true" class="moveToLeft"
                      [minDate]="form.get('fromDate').value" [readonlyInput]="true" [monthNavigator]="true"
                      [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2020:{{ currentYear }}" [locale]="locale" formControlName="toDate">
                    </p-calendar>
                    <label for="toDate">{{ 'devices.general.to' | translate }}</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I tried to make a `class="moveToLeft"` to fix it, but it did not work.

When I do <kbd>F12</kbd>, I see that the left property needs to be changed:

```
<div class="ng-trigger ng-trigger-overlayAnimation ng-tns-c194-50 p-datepicker p-component ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" pr_id_13="" style="z-index: 1001; transform-origin: center top; top: 32px; left: 0px;">
<div class="p-datepicker-group-container ng-tns-c194-50 ng-star-inserted" style="">
<div class="p-datepicker-group ng-tns-c194-50 ng-star-inserted">
<div class="p-datepicker-header ng-tns-c194-50"><button type="button" pripple="" class="p-ripple p-element p-datepicker-prev p-link ng-tns-c194-50 ng-star-inserted">
```

`pr_id_13` corresponds to the "To" `<p-calendar>`.

Finally, I tried in CSS this, but it applies to both date-pickers and it's not what I need:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-datepicker{
  left: -188px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying the following approach as it has worked well for me.

**add `styleClass="yourClass"`**

**1. Template**:

```
  <p-calendar styleClass="yourClass" inputId="basic" [(ngModel)]="date1"></p-calendar>
```

**2. SCSS**:

```
:host ::ng-deep .myClass .p-datepicker {
 left: -188px !important;
}
```